# Replace img tag with H1 tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple GreaseMonkey script. I don't have access to use jQuery.

I need to replace this HTML:

```
<img border="0" title="NEW_UNI_LOGO.png" src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_UNI_LOGO.png"></img>
```

With this HTML:

```
<h1>Production</h1>
```

I have tried:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('body');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        john = cells[i].innerHTML;
        john = john.replace('<img border="0" title="NEW_UNI_LOGO.png" src="/OA_MEDIA/NEW_UNI_LOGO.png"></img>', '<h1>Production</h1>');
        cells[i].innerHTML = john;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

The HTML for the img tag is placed inside a table. The HTML snippet I'm trying to replace only appears once on the page.

Thanks

Comment: Replace the first line with: `var cells = document.body;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Howdy, As i just paste document.querySelectorAll('body'); in my chrome console, it returns the dom mostly, and I believe that running through it will just grab the children of the body, I don't think that the cell you want to replace is directly a child of the body but more nested down no?

Comment: img tag doesn't need to be closed

Comment: Since the `img` here is invalid, the HTML transform it into a valid DOM element and you cant get it with an *exact string replace*...

Comment: Who upvoted my comment, it was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=imgs.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(imgs[i].title == 'NEW_UNI_LOGO.png') {
      var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.innerHTML = 'Production';
      imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore( h1, imgs[i] );
      imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);  
    }
}
```

Here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/4UHHL/

**Or**, you can check the image file name like this:

```
var img_file_name = 'NEW_UNI_LOGO.png'
var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=imgs.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(imgs[i].src.toLowerCase().indexOf('/'+img_file_name.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
      var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.innerHTML = 'Production';
      imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore( h1, imgs[i] );
      imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);  
    }
}
```

Here is the code for this second part: http://jsfiddle.net/Wh2q3/

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried to change to check against the image source rather than title, so used if(imgs[i].src == '/OA_MEDIA/NEW_UNI_LOGO.png') but it's not picking it up - I also tried imgs[i].source just in case, but that didn't work either. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - realised I can use the title attribute after all. Thanks for everyone's help with this

Comment: @dumbo - Check the alternate solution that tests the "src" attribute for the image file name

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var img = document.querySelector("img[title='NEW_UNI_LOGO.png']");
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Production");
img.parentNode.replaceChild(h1,img);
```

This seeks out the specific image element (using the title as an identifier - adjust if needed), and replaces it with a freshly created H1 element.